# Ada mod and rem implementation

Tags: ada, modulus

When looking into exactly what the difference is between mod and rem (something I admittedly should have done years ago, I found little on the matter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation states there are a few different divisions that can be used, and also states which sign the result has for each. If there's any statement about which division is performed in the ARM, I must've missed it. I assume it's Euclidian, but I want to be sure.

*edit:* 
So I had missed this: http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-5.html which covers the relations. However, in the relation for mod:
 A = B*N + (A mod B)
The only mention of N is "in addition, for some signed integer value N". Where does N come from?

Comment: http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-5.html

Comment: This is what I get for trying to look stuff up after pulling an all-nighter. Thanks.

Comment: Kudos for looking; you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188), perhaps citing the more recent [*§4.5.5 Multiplying Operators*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-5.html) and adducing the use case that prompted your question.

Comment: Basically rem is how Fortran, C, Java, C# etc incorrectly implement their mod function, based on the 1950s Fortran implementation.  mod is how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-5.html well explains the fundamental differences in behavior. The tables lower down in the reference manual were of great help. What I eventually came to the conclusion of (and implemented for various fractional types) is that rem uses truncated division, and mod uses floored division. I will edit this answer should I be shown wrong.